# How to completely silence git ls-remote?

Tags: bash, git

I'm writing on a migration bash script for migrating repositories using gitLFS from Github to Gitlab.

One step of it is checking whether the source and destination repositories exist.

On my search I found that `git ls-remote` is perfect for that.

For my script I would like to silence the output of the command (The script itself will check it later) so I'm using `$> /dev/null` like

```
git ls-remote -q <URL to repository> $> /dev/null
```

From [man git ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html)

> `-q`, `--quiet`: Do not print remote URL to stderr.

On success I get no output and `git ls-remote` exits with `0`.

On failure (can be caused by providing incorrect credentials or the repository wasn't found) it exits on `128` but I allways see this ouput

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for '<URL to repository>'
```

or

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository '<URL to repository>' not found
```

**How can I completely silence `git ls-remote`?**

Comment: Reviewers: Unlike some of the other Stack Exchange sites including [unix.se] and [so], as far as I know Ask Ubuntu does *not* have a rule that questions that ultimately turn out to have been about a typo are off-topic. Furthermore, it's not obvious to me that this is actually such a question: confusion about how to write a particular redirection operator is not the same thing as knowing how to write it but typing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to redirect all output & stderr to /dev/null you have to replace

```
git ls-remote -q <URL to repository> $> /dev/null
```

by

```
git ls-remote -q <URL to repository> &> /dev/null
```

(<kbd>&</kbd> instead of <kbd>$</kbd>)

Comment: Oh man :D stupid typo thanks! Don't know why the downvote though but ok ^^

Comment: I make the same typo everytime, it was easy to find ;) Don't know why the downvote either

Comment: Yea never mind .. that's unfortunately how AskUbuntu has become a bit lately

Comment: Seems to me it's a design flaw for any remote output to go to stderr. Hosting services will often use the remote response to nudge you to open a merge request on git push for example. Or are remotes responding incorrectly?

Comment: @Dennis I wanted to completely silence it because I'm using it in a script catching the exit code. I used this line to only check in general whether the provided URL exists and provided credentials are correct. Therefore I didn't want the default error get printed but instead mine. In `git` it isn't any output going to sdterr but .. the output in case of an error ;) which is totally by design. and it is not the remote controlling this behaviour

Comment: Works for other git commands too. Few support the `--quiet` option, which does not completely work in all the cases. Example being git push, only few are suppressed, but not all.